# Property not found on object of type error with method declaration in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Have a weird error on method declaration and call...

```
MyObject.h --- declarations. has been trimmed down
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject

- (void) useFlattenHTML;
- (NSString *) flattenHTML:(NSString *) inHtml;
- (NSString *) justAStringMethod;

@end
```

And method defined and called like this...

```
MyObject.m --- method declaration and usage. Trimmed down
#import "MyObject.h"

@implementation MyObject
- (NSString *) flattenHTML:(NSString *) inHtml {
NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *text = nil;
theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inHtml];
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;
    inHtml = [inHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
}
//
inHtml = [inHtml stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
return inHtml;
}

- (NSString *) justAStringMethod
{
    // Some calls.
}

- (void) useFlattenHTML
{
    NSString* resultStr = [self.flattenHTML @"Some html tagged string"];
    NSString* anotherStr = [self.justAStringMethod]; 
}   

@end
```

I get

```
 Property 'flattenHTML' not found on object of type 'MyObject *'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because you're using the dot notation in a case where it doesn't make much sense :
in `useFlattenHTML` method, `self.flattenHTML` is the same as `[self flattenHTML]`, which doesn't exist, as you only have `[self flattenHTML:someString]`.

On top of that, dot notation is possible, but you should keep it for fields declared as `@property` only

Comment: +1 for you last sentence. I often find people massively misusing dot notation! Although it is possible, it is good practice to follow the standard convention.

Comment: Thanks much. That fixed it. Late night coding. Agree with your last comment about dot notation.